# Concat javascript arrays as array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have these arrays:

```
arr1 = ['29.5',  32035];
arr2 = ['30.5',  32288];
arr3 = ['31.5',  31982];
arr4 = ['1.6',  31768];
```

As a result I want to have something like this:

```
result = [['29.5',  32035], ['30.5',  32288], ['31.5',  31982], ['1.6',  31768]];
```

I means the result is array created by another arrays. The question is, how I can concat the arrays. `result.push.apply(result, arr1);` etc. give me array made by final values.

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: just do `result.push(arr1);` and do that for each `arr1` you got. And i mean 1,2,3,4

Comment: linked "dupe" doesn't really answer this

Answer (score 3):

Actually you can just do

```
var result = [arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4];
```

Or

```
var result = [];
result[0] = arr1;
result[1] = arr2;
result[2] = arr3;
result[3] = arr4;
```

Or

```
var result = [];
result.push(arr1);
result.push(arr2);
result.push(arr3);
result.push(arr4);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using push .

```
var result = [];

result.push(arr1);
result.push(arr2);
result.push(arr3);
result.push(arr4);

console.log(result);
```